# Why does my loop that points to the Dictionary keep printing the same value?

Tags: loops, dictionary, key

Why do I make a loop I don't get :
Cell_num_1
Cell_num_3
Cell_num_5
Cell_num_7

i get always "Cell_num_8"

```
Admin = {
    "Cell_num_1": "NaN",
    "Cell_num_2": 987654321,
    "Cell_num_3": "NaN",
    "Cell_num_4": 123456789,
    "Cell_num_5": "NaN",
    "Cell_num_6": 987654321,
    "Cell_num_7": "NaN",
    "Cell_num_8": 123456789,
}

for values in Admin.values():
    if values =="NaN":
        print (keys)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only looping through values, you can not access the keys in dictionary. Try the following:

```
for key,value in Admin.items():
    if value == "NaN":
        print(key)
```